# Why am I unable to correctly retrieve and use a QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt

I looked up the documentation for creating QTableWidgetItems, and it says that I need to use the `item()` method. 
"Returns the item for the given row and column if one has been set; otherwise returns 0."
Here is how I used it:

`self.table.item(item.row(),1)`

There definitely is an item at these values.
`item.row()` is the row associated with an item in the same row I am trying to return. everything about that item is working fine, and `.text()` returns the correct information. I got that item by using
`self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)`

for some reason it is just this item that I am trying to return that doesn't work. when I go `print(self.table.item(item.row(),1).text())`
it prints nothing, just an empty string. The value it should print is `int(0)`

surrounding with `int()` doesn't work.

Is there some way I can select or return the item at that row and column, and have `.text()` give the `int(0)` that is in there as a result?
Why would it just be printing an empty string when the QTableWidget shows the number 0?

Edit:

```
    self.cur.execute("""SELECT s.StudentID, s.FullName, m.PreviouslyMailed, m.nextMail, m.learnersDate, m.RestrictedDate, m.DefensiveDate FROM
                        StudentProfile s LEFT JOIN Mailouts m ON s.studentID=m.studentID""")
    self.all_data = self.cur.fetchall()
    self.search_results()

    self.table.setRowCount(len(self.all_data))
    self.tableFields = ["Check","REMOVE THIS","Full name","Previously mailed?","Next mail","learners date","Restricted date","Defensive driving date"]
    self.columnList = ["StudentID","FullName","PreviouslyMailed","NextMail","learnersDate","RestrictedDate","DefensiveDate"]
    self.table.setColumnCount(len(self.tableFields))
    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.tableFields)
    self.checkbox_list = []
    for i, item in enumerate(self.all_data):
        FullName = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[1]))
        PreviouslyMailed = QtGui.QComboBox()
        PreviouslyMailed_combobox_list = ["No", "Yes"]
        PreviouslyMailed.addItems(PreviouslyMailed_combobox_list)
        LearnersDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[4]))
        RestrictedDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[5]))
        DefensiveDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[6]))
        NextMail = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[3]))
        StudentID = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[0])
        self.table.setItem(i, 1, StudentID)
        self.table.setItem(i, 2, FullName)
        self.table.setCellWidget(i, 3, PreviouslyMailed)
        self.table.setItem(i, 4, LearnersDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 5, RestrictedDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 6, DefensiveDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 7, NextMail)
        chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.checkbox_list.append(chkBoxItem)
        self.table.setItem(i, 0, self.checkbox_list[i])
        FullName.setFlags(FullName.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        NextMail.setFlags(NextMail.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
    self.table.blockSignals(False)
    self.changed_items = []
    self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)

def log_change(self, item):
    self.table.blockSignals(False)
    self.changed_items.append((self.table.itemAt(item.row(),1),item))

def click_btn_edit(self):
    print("Updating")
    IDList = []
    for item in self.changed_items:
        text, col, row = item[1].text(), item[1].column(), item[1].row()
        new_data = self.all_data
        IDvar = item[0].text()
        #IDvar prints as an empty string.
        IDList.append(IDvar)
```

second edit:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import *
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)


class WindowContainer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.windows = []


def _fromUtf8(t):
    return t

class mainWindowTemplate(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainWindowTemplate"))
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("table"))
        self.table.setColumnCount(0)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.btn_edit = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_edit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_edit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_edit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_edit.clicked.connect(self.click_btn_edit)

        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        """self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)"""

        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.btn_edit.setText("Edit")

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("EDA_Database.db")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        self.show()
        self.click_btn_mailingInfo()


    def retranslateUi(self):

        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))

    def click_btn_mailingInfo(self):
        self.table.blockSignals(True)
        self.screen_name = "mailingInfo"
        self.cur.execute("""SELECT s.StudentID, s.FullName,     m.PreviouslyMailed, m.nextMail, m.learnersDate, m.RestrictedDate, m.DefensiveDate FROM
                        StudentProfile s LEFT JOIN Mailouts m ON s.studentID=m.studentID""")
        self.all_data = self.cur.fetchall()

        self.table.setRowCount(len(self.all_data))
        self.tableFields = ["Check","If you see this column, an error has occured.","Full name","Previously mailed?","Next mail","learners date","Restricted date","Defensive driving date"]
        self.columnList = ["StudentID","FullName","PreviouslyMailed","NextMail","learnersDate","RestrictedDate","DefensiveDate"]
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(self.tableFields))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.tableFields)
        self.checkbox_list = []
        for i, item in enumerate(self.all_data):
            FullName = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[1]))
            PreviouslyMailed = QtGui.QComboBox()
            PreviouslyMailed_combobox_list = ["No", "Yes"]
            PreviouslyMailed.addItems(PreviouslyMailed_combobox_list)
            LearnersDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[4]))
            RestrictedDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[5]))
            DefensiveDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[6]))
            NextMail = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[3]))
            StudentID = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[0]))
            self.table.setItem(i, 1, StudentID)
            self.table.setItem(i, 2, FullName)
            self.table.setCellWidget(i, 3, PreviouslyMailed)
            self.table.setItem(i, 4, LearnersDate)
            self.table.setItem(i, 5, RestrictedDate)
            self.table.setItem(i, 6, DefensiveDate)
            self.table.setItem(i, 7, NextMail)
            chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.checkbox_list.append(chkBoxItem)
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, self.checkbox_list[i])
            FullName.setFlags(FullName.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            NextMail.setFlags(NextMail.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        self.table.setColumnHidden(1, True)
        self.table.blockSignals(False)
        self.changed_items = []
        self.combobox_item_list = []
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)
        #PreviouslyMailed.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_change(None,None,row,1,self.table.cellWidget(row,1).currentText()))

    def log_change(self, item):
        self.table.blockSignals(False)
        self.changed_items.append((self.table.item(item.row(),1),item))

    def click_btn_edit(self):
        IDList = []
        for item in self.changed_items:
            text, col, row = item[1].text(), item[1].column(), item[1].row()
            new_data = self.all_data
            IDvar = item[0].text()

            #no longer works
            print(text)

            #now works
            print(IDvar)

            IDList.append(IDvar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = WindowContainer()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    container.windows.append(mainWindowTemplate())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Schollii edited it, but the wierdest thing happened. my ID now prints correctly, so the thing I wanted to have print now prints the right number, but the .text() from the other item now prints an empty string, it's like I can only have one thing working at a time. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Schollii I ran some tests, and it looks like it is adding the same tuple to `self.changed_items` 4 times, and I don't know why. The first `for` loop in click_btn_edit() goes through each of those identical items, and on the 3rd iteration, the `text` variable prints an empty string, and the program Traces back. Perhaps sorting out why it adds the same item 4 times will solve the issue.

Comment: @Schollii 
Changing anything in one of the items calls the signal for changed items 1 time. When the checkbox is clicked, it is triggered another time. This, however, increases in my main program as I click more tables. if it is the second table I click, it triggers 2 times each for the item and the checkbox. if the table I am editing is the third table I click, it will trigger it 3 times for the item, and 3 times when the checkbox is clicked. How do I get it to only trigger once when the item is changed, and not when the checkbox is ticked?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the qt docs for QTableWidgetItem, you will see that it can only be constructed from another item, from a string, from an icon and a string, or from an integer representing the type id of the item. You are giving the constructor the student ID directly, so it is using that last constructor, which creates an empty item. So,  use this:

```
StudentID = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[0]))
```

Once that is fixed,  you still have the issue that you are connecting to the table itemChanged signal in click_btn_mailingInfo. Verify that this function is only called once (in particular disable line for us to connection s by name to see if it makes a difference).